# Opening JQuery Dialog box onclick of dynamically created linkbuttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have created a blog. A specific group member can chat in that blog. Each comment has a dynamically created linkbutton ("edit"->text)

Upon clicking on the **edit** linkbutton, I want a dialog box to pop up. I tried a lot but unable to proceed. Please help.

Following is the piece of code on how I am trying this.

in .cs file : (this is how I dynamically created the link button) 
(I have used **lnkButtons** class in my jquery.

```
    LinkButton lnkUpdateComment = new LinkButton();
    lnkUpdateComment.ID = "" + objBridgeNotes.BridgeNotesId;
    lnkUpdateComment.Text = "edit";
    lnkUpdateComment.Attributes.Add("class", "lnkButtons");
    lnkUpdateComment.Click += new EventHandler(lnkUpdateComment_Click);
```

.js file:

```
   $(document).ready(function()  {

$(".lnkButtons").live("click", function()  {
    $("#divEditComment").dialog("option", "title", "Edit the Comment");
    $("#divEditComment").dialog("open");
    return true;
});

$(function () {
    var dlg = $("#divEditComment").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "blind",
        //height: 450,
        minWidth: 400,
        //position: ['right', 210],
        buttons: {
            "Update Note": function () {

                var Updates = btnSubmitComment.replace(/_/g, '$');
                __doPostBack(Updates, '');
            }
        }
    });
    dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
});

 });
```

in  .aspx file:

```
        <div id="divEditComment">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updComments" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <table width="100%" style="text-align: center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="divComments" runat="server">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
$(document).on("click",".lnkButtons", function()  {
// desire action
});
```

The `.on()` method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see [`.bind()`](/bind/),  [`.delegate()`](/delegate/), and [`.live()`](/live/). To remove events bound with `.on()`, see [`.off()`](/off/). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, see [`.one()`](/one/)

By **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)**

Comment: No luck Rituraj.  Even here also its not getting inside the function.

Comment: in your html where is .lnkButtons

Comment: and your jquery version should be latest

Comment: I am generating the linkbutton from the code behind.  ... lnkUpdateComment.Attributes.Add("class", "lnkButtons");